# How to select the most recent dates/time and save data in a new table (SQLite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

I want to choose the ID with the most recent date with its recent time from Table 1 and then save that new data in a new table called Table 2. I tried using the function offset but did not work.  I also saw a similar question (to my question) about using the MAX() function but that code did not work as well. Is there a statement to do that? I appreciate all the help!

Table 1

| ID | DATE_1 | RUNTIME_1 | DATE | ENDTIME_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-12 | 10:09:56 | 2021-12-12 | 15:09:56 |
| 1 | 2021-12-12 | 09:09:56 | 2021-12-12 | 16:09:56 |
| 2 | 2020-05-22 | 13:09:12 | 2021-05-22 | 22:09:56 |
| 2 | 2020-05-22 | 09:43:23 | 2021-05-22 | 10:09:56 |
| 2 | 2020-05-21 | 11:43:23 | 2021-05-22 | 21:09:56 |

My goal for Table 2:

| ID | DATE_1 | RUNTIME_1 | DATE | ENDTIME_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-12 | 09:09:56 | 2021-12-12 | 16:09:56 |
| 2 | 2020-05-22 | 13:09:12 | 2021-05-22 | 22:09:56 |

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DATE_1>= DATE AND ENDTIME_1>= RUNTIME_1;
```

Comment: There are 2 dates and 2 times in each row. Which date and time should be max? Also, what is the point of the conditions DATE_1>= DATE AND ENDTIME_1>= RUNTIME_1 in your code?

Comment: DATE and ENDTIME_1 should be max. I thought that these conditions would satisfy for Table 2 even though it did not. I believe I need to be more specific in my conditions, although I am not sure if using MAX() would work.

Comment: Explain the columns. Is `DATE_1` the start date and `DATE` the end date? Based on your "goal for table 2", it looks like you want to copy the latest `DATE` / `ENDTIME_1` for each `DATE_1` year.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I don't see an easy way (if any) to do this with sqlite. Seems to me you need to sort table 1 by ID, DATE descending and ENDTIME_1 descending. Then take the first row for each ID and insert it into table 2. Seems more like something you would need to do in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK()` with `WINDOWING` can be used here -

Query -

```
create table table_2 as 
  with data as 
  (
    select *,  
    dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date_2 || ' '||endtime_1) 
    as etime_rn
    from table1
   )
 select id, date_1, runtime_1, date_2, endtime_1
   from data d
   where etime_rn = (select max(etime_rn) 
      from data d1 where d1.id = d.id 
      group by d1.id);
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=b46f89719f4ef633fd7013efd9517be2).